# Retrieving part of the page body

Tags: html

Is there a way to retrieve only part of a page? I need to access a certain number of characters after the sexdecillionth character, and I know that it is possible. I can't request the page, because it returns response body too large. What should I do?

The platform and language don't matter to me, because I can access them all.

Comment: some more information on the lang you are using, platform, and what you are trying to do might help: I imagine you are talking about a html page and you are trying to buffer the response... Or are we talking about memory "pages" :)

Comment: This is a challenge from hacker.org. Please delete this question or edit/remove at least the name of the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve it from what?

Generally speaking, you'll need to open an HTTP connection and use the [Range: header](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Feb/07/Using-HTTP-Ranges-to-resume-resume-aborted-downloads) to request the start location of the page download.  I don't know that every web server supports it, though, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Or more precisely, retrieve it IN what?  The exact implementation will vary depending on what language/client you're using.